# Codeblocks stop executing with gnome-terminal (linux)

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

I have kali linux, I have been using codeblocks and it worked fine with gnome-terminal,but a few days ago, it stop working. I write a c++ code, then build the file and execute, but when I execute , it does nothing, codeblocks just doesn't want to launch with gnome-terminal.

How I can fix it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

From Settings > Environment,

replace
Code: [Select]

```
xterm -T $TITLE -e
```

with
    Code: [Select]

```
gnome-terminal --title=$TITLE -x
```

Comment: yes, I mean , I did that and codeblocks was working with gnone-terminal, but then it just stop working and don't execute with it.  thanks for your answer